# symfony 2 :a question about form

Tags: forms, symfony1

I try to realize such a effect in a form of creating a new category : I add a 'select list' to the form to show all the category i have created  ,so I tried:

```
> /**
>      * @var string $parent
>      *
>      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductCategory")
>      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_category_id",
> referencedColumnName="id")  
>      */
>      
>     private $parent;
```

then i want to realize that:if the checkbox isRoot is selected ,the parent option is set "root",so i wrote:

```
> if($entity->getIsRoot()){
>             $entity ->setParent('root');
>         }
```

However,it give me a exception: 
      Expected argument of type "object", "string" given

what's the matter? How to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that the

```
->setParent()
```

expects an object of type Category.

Since you don't want to select a parent category for root nodes, you should not set the parent.

Comment: But if i don't set the parent ,it will be set the first option ,because in the form ,there is a select list for parent ,and the choices is the category i have created.  Do you know how to add an 'default' option or a blank option to the select list?

Comment: Soleved! Thank you for attention!